# Unity Build Error: "minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library"

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, gradle, android-manifest

I try to Build my old Unity Project (using **Unity 2017.4**) to Android `App Bundle`, However it never success because of this error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
C:/Program Files/AdoptOpenJDK/jdk-8.0.252.09-hotspot\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2017.4.39f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.4.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "bundleRelease"

stderr[
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PRJ\(Original Backup) my card game (Unity 2017.4)\Temp\gradleOut\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [:udp:] C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b3f88f65a3796181b242bb4c7bfbd43c\udp\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 1
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 15,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.unity.udp.sdk" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processReleaseManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 1 cannot be smaller than version 15 declared in library [:udp:] C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\b3f88f65a3796181b242bb4c7bfbd43c\udp\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 1
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 1,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 15,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.unity.udp.sdk" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
]
stdout[

> Configure project :
WARNING: The option setting 'android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false' is experimental and unsupported.
The current default is 'true'.

WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed soon. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
WARNING: DSL element 'useProguard' is obsolete and will be removed soon. Use 'android.enableR8' in gradle.properties to switch between R8 and Proguard..
WARNING: DSL element 'useProguard' is obsolete and will be removed soon. Use 'android.enableR8' in gradle.properties to switch between R8 and Proguard..

> Task :preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileReleaseRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :checkReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :mainApkListPersistenceRelease UP-TO-DATE

> Task :processReleaseManifest FAILED

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.

6 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 5 up-to-date
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1 progress, System.String error)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1 progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

My Efforts so far: "Find All variables about min-SDK in the Unity's Plugin folder and set it to 15". However still failed.

Note, I use these Plugins:

- Easy Save 3
- Energy Bar Toolkit
- PlayMaker
- PlayMaker EcoBrowser (Custom Scripts)
- Dotween
- Dotween PlayMaker Actions
- UI Pagination
- Doozy UI (old version - not available anymore in asset store)
- Ez (deprecated - not available anymore in asset store)
- TextMeshPro (old version)

Any Idea?

Comment: `Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Hi thanks, now it solved...

Answer (score 2):

Select higher version of API from drop down in Player Settings of Unity for Android